# Entity Factory Standard Objects

Tags: entity-framework, optimization, factory-pattern

I can't find an existing question for this, so sorry if it is a re-ask.

I'm designing an entity factory system for an mmorpg, and I want to optimize memory use for standard objects (objects where every instance is the same eg. potions) so that mass quantities of an object only hold a reference and not all of the relevant data.

I assume I just have a component that refers to the factory constructor, but this is my first attempt at this kind of system so I want to make sure before I code myself into a hole.

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a design issue than an entity framework issue. You should try to read about what the factory pattern does! There are plenty of good guides on the internet, like http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee817667.aspx
When you know what the pattern does letting your factory return either a standard object from your database or a new one should be fairly easy.

Consider for example: when you have a potion factory, you will give it some kind of input and based on that input, the factory will return you a kind of potion. This could be a potion from your database(the standard potion!) and will thus save you a new record.

For example

```
public IPotion GetPotion(PotionType potion, EFContext context)
{
    switch (potion)
    {
        case PotionType.Health:
            // return standard health potion from the context
        break;
        case PotionType.Custom:
            // return a new instance of some sort of customizable IPotion, added to the context
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: What I'm trying to do is save memory. I get how to get a potion object, but if the user has 100s of them, I want them to be simple pointers rather than each instance hold the variables for the potion.

Comment: As long as you are working within the same database context, every time you retrieve that same potion from the database it will be the same object in memory. This is described Here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/bb896269%28v=vs.100%29.aspx under "Identity Resolution and Merge Options"

Comment: Sorry I must have misunderstood what I read.
I thought that the EntityDB stored in game instances, which were created by calling the corresponding factory.
So is the EntityDB meant to store the definition of each game object (potion, hi-potion, max-potion) and the in game objects store the entity key and any individual data (creature current hp)?